# Add overlay text to firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm coding a subtitle displayer extension for firefox to overlay custom subtitles to streamed videos that don't have them. It's my first extension.

How can I overlay a line of text on firefox?

If that's not possible, how to create a pane where subtitles can be printed?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK)? There are some pretty explicit tutorials there on how to do both things you're asking.

Comment: I am looking at overlays as Noitidart suggested. And also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_the_Page_Hosted_by_a_Tab which is very close of what I intend to do.

Comment: Here, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/carmijoon/pZbkX/ But I believe it is likely it won't support the streaming websites I usually use, so probably something independent of the content is better. The docs example seem to do just that, we'll see.

Comment: If you want to use the add-SDK, which is much easier, follow the instructions of that tutorial. @Noitidart's instructions are for [bootstrapped extenions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions)

Answer (score 1):

You can just overlay the video elements with html.

However if you want to overlay everything then you have to create xul panel. Here is how to create panels:

```
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var panel = win.document.createElement('panel');
var props = {
    type: 'arrow',
    style: 'width:300px;height:100px;'
}
for (var p in props) {
    panel.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}

win.document.querySelector('#mainPopupSet').appendChild(panel);

panel.addEventListener('popuphiding', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //panel.removeEventListener('popuphiding', arguments.callee, false); //if dont have this then cant do hidepopup after animation as hiding will be prevented
    panel.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
        //panel.hidePopup(); //just hide it, if want this then comment out line 19 also uncomment line 16
        panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel); //remove it from dom //if want this then comment out line 18
    }, false);
    panel.ownerDocument.getAnonymousNodes(panel)[0].setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(0,-50px);opacity:0.9;transition: transform 0.2s ease-in, opacity 0.15s ease-in');
}, false);

panel.openPopup(null, 'overlap', 100, 100);
```

from: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9130024

see also:

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9445992